# Why do the created elements desappear from the webseite directly after their creation?

Tags: javascript, forms, submit, createelement

After input of:
Number
Text (which to be added in the div elements as text)
Select (Div or Section)

and after clicking on the Create-Button

the given number of divs will appear in the section.

This occur too but like I said all those created div elements disappear afterwards.

I changed the code several time but without any success :(

```
//HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="de">
  <title>Kontaktlistenbeispiel</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="mainWeek12Challenge6.css" >
</head>
<body>
  <form action="">
    <input type="number" name="elements" class="input" placeholder="Number Of Elements" />
    <input type="text" name="texts" class="input" placeholder="Elements Text" />
    <select name="type" class="input">
      <option value="Div">Div</option>
      <option value="Section">Section</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="create" value="Create" />
    <div class="results"></div>
  </form>

  <script src="main6.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

// JS
const formEl = document.querySelector('form');
const numberInputEl = document.querySelector('input[type="number"]');
const textInputEl = document.querySelector('input[type="text"]');
const resultSection = document.querySelector('.results');
const selectionEle = document.querySelector('select');
const containerEl = document.createElement(selectionEle.value);
containerEl.style.cssText = "display: flex; justify-content: center; gap:10px;";

formEl.addEventListener('submit', constructElements);

function constructElements() {
    const containerEl = document.createElement(selectionEle.value);
    containerEl.style.cssText = "display: flex; justify-content: center; gap:10px;";
    let i = 0;
    while(i < parseInt(numberInputEl.value)) {
        const currDiv = document.createElement('div');
        currDiv.className = 'newDiv';
        currDiv.textContent = textInputEl.value;
        containerEl.appendChild(currDiv);
        i++;
    }

    resultSection.appendChild(containerEl);
}
```

Comment: You forgot to prevent the form's default submit action, so the page reloads.

Comment: The issue has been resolved. I needed to include the following: event.preventDefault(), to prevent the form from redirecting to another page specified in the action attribute.